# Count down floors

Tags: python, countdown

I have nearly fixed this to the point it needs, but one thing I can't seem to get is the floor I'm on. The code needs to count down the floors from say floor 2 to floor 6 including the floor 2 in the countdown. Mine only goes from next floor up to the one down, say floor 3 to floor 6. I need help to fix this please.

```
floor = int(input('Current floor: '))
destination = input('Desination floor: ')
while floor <= 5:
  floor = floor + 1
  print(floor)
```

Comment: do you want to do this in javascript

Comment: lol.... no way, thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print before you increment floor (`floor = floor + 1`). You left the while loop at `5`, which I assume should be the destination. A final `print` or a modification to the while loop may be needed.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your time in helping me.

Comment: Jumped too fast. Now have another problem. I have the code like this: floor = int(input('Current floor: '))
destination = input('Desination floor: ')
while floor <= 6:
  print ('Level' +floor)       
  floor = floor + 1                   .... it now comes back at me with this now: Current floor: 3
Desination floor: 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 4, in <module>
    print ('Level' +floor)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: @StuartWalsh You are trying to combine a string and an integer. Convert the int to str with str()

Comment: Hmm, did that, made the int into a str and it came back with this: Current floor: 3
Desination floor: 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 3, in <module>
    while floor <= 6:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() <= int() ....... the code now reads: floor = (str)(input('Current floor: '))
destination = input('Desination floor: ')
while floor <= 6:
  print ('Level' +floor)
  floor = floor + 1                    .... You'll have ignore my ignorance in this, I know the theory of Python, which as a teacher I need to know, but not real good at coding, I do get some right.

Comment: @StuartWalsh you should put this issue in another question...or learn more about types str and int

Comment: Why should it go in another question area? I started this for this question. And I'm trying to learn more, but it all goes over my head.

Comment: @StuartWalsh The original question has been answered